# Can't get into trunk of 2000 mercury marquis

Tags: repair, mercury, grand-marquis, trunk

Anyone have any ideas to get into a locked, jammed trunk of a 2000 mercury marquis?
They key, the remote, and the button on the door all do not work, although a clicking sound is produced.  You can't access through back seat.
I think its because some unnamed unsmart person jammed a ton of stuff in there (strollers, spare tire, tote box, chair)  and its somehow interfering with the mechanism.

Answer (score 17):

If the trunk was overfilled and had to be pushed closed, you might have success with pushing down on the trunk (with as much force as you safely can) while trying to operate the mechanism.  If a force inside the trunk is pushing up, the mechanism could be in a bind.  You pushing down will hopefully counteract that force enough to free up the lock.

Comment: This is actually how I open the trunk of any 15+ year old hatchback or station wagon by default (though not with _as much force as available_) and it works all the time.

Comment: Sitting on the trunk would probably provide the force needed without killing yourself in the process.

Answer (score 14):

Even if the seat does not fold down, you can unbolt it.  Remove the bottom part first, then the back.  This happened in my mother's Camry several times(bad latch mechanism) and I had to remove the seat each time.

Comment: Great advice.  I would expect the seats to be bolted from the trunk side so I wouldn't have even considered this.  Good to know it's an option on at least some cars.

Comment: All of the ones I have seen (mostly late 80's, early 90's) are bolted in the front.  I assume so you can get to the trunk if the latch fails.  Usually the bottom has tabs in the back and either bolts or tabs up front.  The back of the seat either has tabs up top that go into the 'shelf', or bolts in on the side, and bolts on the bottom.

Comment: Just be thankful it's not a 2-door car where you have to remove the front seats to get the rear ones out! There has got to be *some* method of access by folding or removing the rear seat.

Answer (score 1):

**Jam your hand up in there**

Move crap around.  push on it really hard, various things and keep hitting the remote while you do it.  Eventually you will get into the trunk with brute force....but damage anything on you path.

You can reach in there and do it.  My kid did it for a Malibu so you should be able to with the same.

I have one here, 2003, if you want me try anything.